# RxJs throwError does not trigger catch in Promise

Tags: promise, rxjs, observable

I've got an Api call that is converted to a promise.  My handleError function inside the observable re-throws via throwError.  This re-thrown error does not trigger any catch in the outer Promise chain.

```
callApi() {    
  return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/someapi`)
    .pipe(
      map((data: any) => this.extractData(data)),
      catchError(error => this.handleError(error))
    ).toPromise();

handleError(error) {
  console.error(error);
  return throwError(error || 'Server error');
}
```

Calling code...

```
this.someService.callApi()
  .then((response) => {
    // THIS GETS CALLED AFTER throwError
    // do something cool with response
    this.someVar = response;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // WE NEVER GET TO HERE, even when I force my api to throw an error
    console.log(`Custom error message here. error = ${error.message}`);
    this.displayErrorGettingToken();
  });
```

Why doesn't the throwError trigger the Promise catch?

Comment: Where exactly is the error being triggered? If it's the HTTP call, when what you've got should work. If the error is being triggered from within `this.extractData()`, what you've got should still work provided you're using the `throw new Error` form and not simply returning a `throwError`. If you're doing the latter, swap the `map` for a `switchMap`. (As an aside, mixing promises and observables seems unusual, so I hope you know what you're doing.)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `toPromise()` when possible. 
Use **subscribe** instead of then. 
Also when you catch the error in a pipe it won't be thrown in then because you already caught it, also when you throw the error in a catch error, it won't be emitted into the regular pipe flow of your response.

```js
callApi() {    
  return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/someapi`);
}
```

This is totally ok. `Http.get()` returns a singleton observable stream, which emits only ONE value and then completes. Subscribe to the `Observable`.

```js
this.someService.callApi()
  .subscribe((response) => {
    // THIS GETS CALLED always wenn everything is ok
    this.someVar = response;
  }, 
  (error:HttpErrorResponse) =>{
       console.log(`Custom error message here. error ${error.message}`);
    this.displayErrorGettingToken();
  });
```

`Observable` is like an extended version of promise. Use it.